# How to resize image if the image is bigger than Textbox.But it not increase scale if smaller

Tags: image, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I created RDLC report layouts by  using Visual Studio Report Designer.

I need to display image on textbox.
The image was set center align by  [Chris Hays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx) 's method.
But This method must set sizing to be "Clip"

[image]

So It has a problem because  when Image which it was getting from database is bigger than textbox. It would clipped like below.

[image]

I tried to use sizing with "Fit Proportional" Mode. It can't set centered image by  [Chris Hays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx) 's method.

But if I use sizing with "Fit to size". I can ignore centered image. But if some image is very small. It will lose quality.

What should I do if I need to

**1.Centered image**

**2.Fit to textbox** if image is bigger than textbox.

**3.Original size** if image is smaller that textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can resolved this problem by created two image control.

**First image control -It was set sizing "Fit"**

**Second image control- It was set sizing "Clip" and used Chris Hays 's method for centered image.**

Both two image controls was set Visibility property by  expression

if a width of image is bigger than textbox , First image control will show and second will hide.

if a width of image is smaller than textbox , First image control will hide and second will show.

I can get a width of image by this code

```
       =(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!FILE_BINARY_DATA.Value, "My Table"),Byte()))).Width /96)
```

**96** is dpi

After I known  a width of image from above expression.
I will use it for set Visibility Property of First Image like these

```
     =iif((imgWidthInch.Value  > 2.6  ),false,true)
```

**2.6** is widht of my textbox.

And Set Visibility of Second Image by the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same sizes of the tutorial you could try and set the `Sizing` property by using the following expression:

```
=IIF(Round((3.5-System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(Fields!LargePhoto.Value,Byte()))).Width
/96)/2,2)>0, "Clip", "Fit")
```

Comment: I think Sizing property of Image control can't set with Expression.