# Resize an image in SSRS using an expression so it stays small in a subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have scoured the internet and tried for many hours to solve this but have not been able to find a solution. Are there any SSRS masters out there that know how to resize an image in SSRS using an expression or code of some kind?  I am simply trying to create a thumbnail of a larger image to go in a tablix in my report.  The thumbnail gives a preview of the image, and the user can then click it to get the bigger version via a hyperlink.  The report is delivered via email from a subscription from SSRS.  Two problems are occuring:  1. the original sized file seems to be in the report, so the PDF that gets delivered is huge. 2. The thumbnail images which look right when run from report builder blow up to original size (I've read that this has to do with Outlook not allowing javascript to run/not allowing for resize).  Can anyone help point me in the right direction here?  Let me know if you have questions, and I'll try my best to clarify.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using something like this?

```
=(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(First(Fields!FILE_BINARY_DATA.Value, "My Table"),Byte()))).Width /96)
```

Taken from [How to resize image if the image is bigger than Textbox.But it not increase scale if smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491334/how-to-resize-image-if-the-image-is-bigger-than-textbox-but-it-not-increase-scal)

Comment: Wow, I'll have to study that line of code. Seems like a lot going on there. Thank you so much for the help.  Sorry for the delayed response.